# When the checkbox is checked, insert numbering on table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

```
<td>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!child.Confirm_Order__c}" />
</td>
    //checkbox
<td>
    <!-- <apex:panelGroup rendered="{!child.Confirm_Order__c==true}">-->
    <apex:inputfield value="{!child.Order_numbering__c}" id="getindex" />
      //text field
    <!-- </apex:panelGroup>-->
</td>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" onclick="insert_numbers()" />
```

Html:

```
<table>
<th><td>Checkbox value</td><td>Inputfield value</td></th>
<tr>
<td>true</td><td>1</td>
<td>false</td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>true</td><td>2</td>
<td>false</td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
    function insert_numbers() {
        $("[id$=getindex]").each(function(index) {
            $(this).val(index + 1)
        })
    }
</script>
```

Currently it is working fine. It inserts a number for every td.

I want to modify this in such a way that when a checkbox is checked, numbers are inserted in input field td as 1, 2, 3... (I want to insert number to those td checkbox was checked .remaining as blank)

(or)

I won't show input field td whenever checkbox is not checked. Then I want to do number to those td with input field visible.

Currently it is not inserting if td is not avaliable in middle of the row.

How I can do this?